# Html.fromHtml() removes carriage-returns "&#xD", "\n"

Tags: android, xml, httpresponse

As a response I am getting a string which is windows .ini file each pair has `&#xD` in the end this is the carriage-return in Canonical XML. 
After

```
String ini = Html.fromHtml(response).toString();
```

ini gets string with no line breaks instead of them white-spaces. How to keep line-breaks on their places?

Response comes as

> <string
>   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">&lt;?xml version="1.0"
>   encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&lt;Profile&gt;[General]&#xD;AutoRecoveryConversion=1&#xD;UpdateExistingBootScreen=0&#xD;EnableTraditionalBL=1....

and I have to deal with it as is, no change will be provided from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `&amp;#xD;` replaced in response string with `<br/>` output string contains proper line breaks.