# How to make a link INSIDE a string resource (along with other text in it) ? - Android

Tags: android, url, text, hyperlink

For example: Take a look at the following string resource:

```
 <string name="b1b">This link will take you to google.com. More text here.</string>
```

Now I want this string resource to look like this in my app:

> This link will take you to [Google](https://www.google.com/). More text here.

I can't use three textviews. This was just an example. So I can't make the entire textview a link.

(Why?
What I'm doing in my app is … I have say a dozen buttons, each of them sends a string resource ID as an intent to a "Text Shower Activity" … and in that I simply have a single textview which shows different texts based on which button the user clicked. So, I'm saving on app size.

Plus every such text string resource has different number of links at different places, so it's not feasible to have a single textview just for links and somehow weave it in between.)

So, I need to make a little bit of the string resource into a link. I've tried the `<a>` thing with no effect.

How to do this?

Comment: you want "This link will take you to google.com." to make it a link?

Comment: I just want { "TEXT HERE" + LINK + "TEXT HERE" } ...in a single textview. The {...} is a single resource

Answer (score 10):

Example  XML resource:

```
</string name="mlink">
    to go to Google<![CDATA[ <a href="http://google.com">click here</a>]]> 
    and <![CDATA[<a href="http://yahoo.com">this</a>]]> moves you to yahoo!
</string>
```

Java:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.mlink)));
```

Note that you need to put your html link inside the `CDATA` tag, this is the proper way to use links in String resources.

Comment: Hey there ! That works great but ... It threw my formatting in the trashcan... For one, it's now ignoring all the newline escape characters... But the link works ... How to restore the formatting ?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121799/html-fromhtml-removes-carriage-returs-xd-n  and similar questions

Comment: @Droidman as per this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML the < brackets should be replaced with &lt;. But after that I am getting error at build time as that "]]> should be used only with CDATA opening"

Comment: @Nainal if your HTML is inside a CDATA block, you don't need to replace anything

Answer (score 2):

Just to add on @Droidman's answer if anyone wants to use it without CDATA, Below will also work without CDATA but we have to escaped the characters such as "<" , using the &lt; notation.

```
</string name="mlink">
to go to Google &lt;a href=\"http://google.com\"&gt;click here&lt;/a&gt; 
and &lt;a href=\"http://yahoo.com\"&gt;this&lt;/a&gt; moves you to yahoo!
</string>
```

Java:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.mlink)));
```