# How to including a link in a body of text in android string resource

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have a string resource named `large_text` as

```
<string name="large_text"> 
  "lots of texts"
  ...
  "lots more text\n\n"
  ...
  "I was not kidding"
  "so here is the phrase I want to make a hyperlink"
</string>
```

So how do I make a short phrase within that large body of text into a hyperlink? [The suggestion here is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311351/how-to-make-a-link-inside-a-string-resource-along-with-other-text-in-it-an): `string.xml` will not even compile. It gives the error that

> Error: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character
>   data or markup.

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced this issue while using it from strings.xml so i ended up using it like this and it works for me.

```
 useageTerms.setText(Html.fromHtml("By tapping register, you agree to the\n " +
            "<a href=\"http://www.google.in/terms.html\">Terms & Conditions</a> for Google"));
 useageTerms.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```