# Create a Hyperlink using String resources

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-resources

I try to make a TextView as hyperlink. This one worked as expected :

```
content.text = "<a href=${args.article.url}>Content</a>".fromHtml()
```

But I get a lint warning regarding using string resources. But this one does now show TextView as hyperlink:

```
content.text = getString(R.string.content, args.article.url).fromHtml()
```

And this is String resource :

```
<string name="content"><a href="%s">Content</a></string>
```

Is there any solution to fix it using String resource?

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun String.fromHtml() = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Html.fromHtml(this, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
} else {
    Html.fromHtml(this)
}
```

Comment: Use `getText()` instead of `getString()`/`fromHtml()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19311520/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare, when I use `getText(R.string.content, args.article.url).fromHtml()` I receive an error under `args.article.url`

Comment: Oh, right, `getText()` doesn't support placeholders. You could switch to the single-parameter `getText()` and use [`TextUtils.expandTemplate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#expandTemplate(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence...)) or `TextUtils.replace()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I used `TextUtils.expandTemplate(getText(R.string.content), args.article.url).toString().fromHtml()`, but TextView is not shown as hyperlink. Isn't it related to how I defined string resource?

Comment: [The answer that I linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19311520/115145) uses `CDATA` -- did you convert your string resource to use that?

Comment: Yes, that was right. Thanks. You can share your answer and I mark it as accepted.

Comment: I recommend that you answer your own question, showing what you wound up with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to set text in TextView :

```
content.text = TextUtils.expandTemplate(getText(R.string.content), args.article.url).toString().fromHtml()
```

And this is how to set String resources :

```
<string name="content"><![CDATA[ <a href="$s">Content</a>]]></string>
```